# Anyone know how to turn off debugging / Logging in DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I just setup a logging provider using Log4net and noticed when testing that DotNetOpenAuth is logging messages as well. They must be using log4net as well, great I don't want 50 inserts everytime someone logs in with an openID..

Anyway to turn this off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yes](http://dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/loggingdebugging-dotnetopenauth-with-log4net/).

```
<configuration>
    <log4net>
        <logger name="DotNetOpenAuth">
            <level value="ERROR" />
        </logger>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @Andrew, if I am not using log4net at all, how can I disable logging? (I mean without log4net assembly in bin or GAC)

Comment: @airmanx86 DNOA works fine without log4net.dll anywhere. But if it's absent, DNOA will try to log to System.Diagnostics.Trace.  You can prevent that by just adjusting the standard .NET trace verbosity level.